# How can I set default protocol used in cordova android to http than https?

Tags: javascript, android, http, cordova, https

**Development**

I have an app written with JavaScript, JQuery and HTML. The app consumes data from rails API via AJAX calls over using HTTP protocol.

**Problem**

I am using cordova to build the application to android app. Building the application android works, however I am not able to connect the rails server. When I checked the URL used to get data from the rails API, it has HTTPS as protocol not HTTP.

I tried building the same app to electron app using the same cordova and it uses HTTP and able to connect to rails API.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Please check out this use clear text setting: https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/11.x/guide/platforms/android/index.html#android-quirks

Also consider upgrading your server to HTTPS.